# Batch script to bypass VPN for certain domains

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, network-programming, vpn

I've been using a VPN service for some time but some websites (twitch.tv) do not allow me to connect to them via a VPN. So I looked up how to bypass the VPN for these domains on Windows and found static routing.

How I wanted to do it was with a batch file to run on startup that automatically routes all the ip adresses of a set of given
   domains.

- independent of default gateway adress
- independent of the network adapter in use
- requires no tweaking after the domain changes ip address
- deals with the entire set of domain ip adresses (nslookup?)

This is what I came up with through trial and error.

```
@echo off

FOR /F "tokens=3" %%F in (
    'route print ^|findstr "\<0.0.0.0\>"'
) Do if not defined DefaultGateway set "DefaultGateway=%%F"

FOR /F "tokens=2" %%F in ('nslookup twitch.tv') DO (
    SET var1=%%F
)
route -p add %var1% mask 255.255.255.255 %DefaultGateway%

FOR /F "skip=5 tokens=1" %%F IN ('nslookup twitch.tv') DO (
   route -p add %%F mask 255.255.255.255 %DefaultGateway%
)
```

I think you can tell that this is some hideous frankenstein code that I created from snippets found on SO. It works for now, but how would I make it more elegant? Could the second and third FOR loop be combined into one? How do I make it so that if I were to add a new domain I could just add it to a list instead of adding another 2 FOR loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been using this batch file:

```c
set domains=twitch.tv google.com some-domain.com

for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('route print ^| findstr "\<0.0.0.0\>"') do (
    for %%d in (%domains%) do (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 skip=4" %%b in ('nslookup %%d 2^>nul') do (
            if "%%c"=="" (route add %%b %%a) else (route add %%c %%a)
        )
    )
    goto done
)
:done
```

It grabs the first `0.0.0.0` route's gateway and uses it to add the routes for the specified domains, their IP addresses obtained via `nslookup`.

And it was scheduled to run whenever the connection was established via `Task Scheduler -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Ras` with the trigger `On an event / Application / RasClient / 20225`.

Comment: After trying thisone out, it does not work. It does not fullfull "independent of the network adapter in use". It takes the default gateway from the wrong adapter for me.

Comment: Also, the 'nslookup -query^=any [domain]' command doesn't always return an internet adress.

Comment: No, I still get a 'draft-jabley-dnsop-refuse-any' response from some domains. I think some dont respond to a QTYPE=ANY query.

Comment: That is almost right, the "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" is nice but now it also adds a static route for the dns server (the first ip adress returned by nslookup). Also, tokens=4 returns my local ip instead of the default gateway. It really has to be 3 in my case haha.

Comment: This works! If you update your OP I can accept it as the answer.